why huge local variable array doesnt cause segment fault
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    char arr[40960];

    for(auto i =0;i<40960;++i)
        arr[i]='c';

    std::cout<<sizeof(arr)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
       

we're taught local variables allocate in stack ,so we can't take up too many byte of stack , but in this case program doesnt crash, does anyone know what magic compiler does?

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 14.1.1 20240522
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

disassemble code:

0000000000001159 <main>:
    1159:   55                      push   %rbp
    115a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    115d:   48 81 ec 20 a0 00 00    sub    $0xa020,%rsp
    1164:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    116b:   00 00 
    116d:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    1171:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    1173:   c7 85 ec 5f ff ff 00    movl   $0x0,-0xa014(%rbp)
    117a:   00 00 00 
    117d:   eb 17                   jmp    1196 <main+0x3d>
    117f:   8b 85 ec 5f ff ff       mov    -0xa014(%rbp),%eax
    1185:   48 98                   cltq
    1187:   c6 84 05 f0 5f ff ff    movb   $0x63,-0xa010(%rbp,%rax,1)
    118e:   63 
    118f:   83 85 ec 5f ff ff 01    addl   $0x1,-0xa014(%rbp)
    1196:   81 bd ec 5f ff ff ff    cmpl   $0x9fff,-0xa014(%rbp)
    119d:   9f 00 00 
    11a0:   7e dd                   jle    117f <main+0x26>
    11a2:   be 00 a0 00 00          mov    $0xa000,%esi
    11a7:   48 8d 05 92 2e 00 00    lea    0x2e92(%rip),%rax        # 4040 <_ZSt4cout@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    11ae:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    11b1:   e8 7a fe ff ff          call   1030 <_ZNSolsEm@plt>
    11b6:   48 8b 15 03 2e 00 00    mov    0x2e03(%rip),%rdx        # 3fc0 <_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    11bd:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
    11c0:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    11c3:   e8 78 fe ff ff          call   1040 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
    11c8:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    11cd:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
    11d1:   64 48 2b 14 25 28 00    sub    %fs:0x28,%rdx
    11d8:   00 00 
    11da:   74 05                   je     11e1 <main+0x88>
    11dc:   e8 6f fe ff ff          call   1050 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
    11e1:   c9                      leave
    11e2:   c3                      ret

sorry for my bad english

Aparently your stack is big enough to hold 40960 chars. The stack is reletively small, but not that small.

40960 is not very big. Also since you don't actually do anything with the array the compiler could just remove it, even if it was one billion bytes big.

40k is not very big, try allocating more than 1MB

Your array is 40kiB big. Typical stack has 1-8 MiB.

It seems that the array allocation is optimized away (even in O0 which I find surprising). You've got a stackoverflow with msvc in debug mode

@Oersted I don't get a stackoverflow with MSVC in debug mode. I think the default stack size is 1MB which is more than enough here.

@wohlstad Ah I tested on godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/P5cTPzn8K

40960 bytes is barely 41 kilobytes. On most systems, the maximum stack size is roughly 8000000 bytes. It is much smaller on embedded systems and even more, it is OS dependent but can be manipulated at compile time. Try it here on Compiler Explorer. The maximum stack size over there is 8382043 bytes hence char arr[8382044] causes a stack overflow. This can change in the future though.
